# Detecting the locked table or row in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2012, locking

I'm trying to understand/learn how to track down the details of a blocked session.

So I created the following setup:

```
create table foo (id integer not null primary key, some_data varchar(20));
insert into foo values (1, 'foo');
commit;
```

Now I connect to the database twice from two different clients.

The first session issues:

```
begin transaction
update foo set some_data = 'update'
  where id = 1;
```

I explicitly do **not** commit there in order to keep the locks.

In the second session I issue the same statement and of course that one waits due to locking. Now I'm trying to use the different queries floating around in order to see that session 2 is waiting for the `foo` table.

`sp_who2` shows the following (I removed some columns to only show the important information):

```
SPID | Status       | BlkBy | DBName   | Command          | SPID | REQUESTID
-----+--------------+-------+----------+------------------+------+----------
52   | sleeping     |   .   | foodb    | AWAITING COMMAND | 52   | 0        
53   | sleeping     |   .   | foodb    | AWAITING COMMAND | 53   | 0        
54   | SUSPENDED    | 52    | foodb    | UPDATE           | 54   | 0        
56   | RUNNABLE     |   .   | foodb    | SELECT INTO      | 56   | 0
```

This is expected, session 54 is blocked by the un-committed changes from session 52.

Querying `sys.dm_os_waiting_tasks` also shows this. The statement:

```
select session_id, wait_type, resource_address, resource_description
from sys.dm_os_waiting_tasks
where blocking_session_id is not null;
```

returns:

```
session_id | wait_type | resource_address   | resource_description                                                            
-----------+-----------+--------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        54 | LCK_M_X   | 0x000000002a35cd40 | keylock hobtid=72057594046054400 dbid=6 id=lock4ed1dd780 mode=X associatedObjectId=72057594046054400
```

Again this is expected.

My problem is, that I can't figure out how to find the actual object name that session 54 is waiting for.

I have found several queries that are joining `sys.dm_tran_locks` and `sys.dm_os_waiting_tasks` like this:

```
SELECT ....
FROM sys.dm_tran_locks AS l
  JOIN sys.dm_os_waiting_tasks AS wt ON wt.resource_address = l.lock_owner_address
```

But in my above test scenario this join does not return anything. So either that join is wrong or `dm_tran_locks` doesn't actually contain the information I'm looking for.

So what I am looking for is a query that returns something like: 
 
"*session 54 is waiting for a lock in table `foo`*".

---

Some background info:

The real life problem I'm trying to solve is a bit more complicated, but boils down to the question "on which table is session 54 waiting for". The problem in question involves a largish stored procedure that updates several tables and a select from a view that accesses some of those tables. The `select` statement is blocked even though we have snapshot isolation and read committed snapshot enabled. Figuring out *why* the select is blocked (which I thought would not be possible if snapshot isolation is enabled) will be the next step.

As a first step I'd like to find out on *what* that session is waiting.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190345.aspx says your join is correct.

Comment: @MaxVernon: thanks for confirming that. But then I'm even more confused. Why does it not return anything although I _know_ there is a lock and a blocked session?

Comment: I'm unable to recreate the problem you are seeing in SQL Server 2012.  I created a test database, enabled RCSI, created your tables, and ran both update statements, and I see a row returned by your last query.

Comment: If you want a visual aid in detecting your locks there is an open source tool available called SQL lock finder. You can find the source on: https://github.com/LucBos/SqlLockFinder Or download the executable on: http://sqllockfinder.com We also love any contributions you could make to the code so we can make it better.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I think this does what you need.

```
USE 'yourDB'
GO
SELECT  
    OBJECT_NAME(p.[object_id]) BlockedObject
FROM    sys.dm_exec_connections AS blocking
    INNER JOIN sys.dm_exec_requests blocked
        ON blocking.session_id = blocked.blocking_session_id
    INNER JOIN sys.dm_os_waiting_tasks waitstats
        ON waitstats.session_id = blocked.session_id
    INNER JOIN sys.partitions p ON SUBSTRING(resource_description, 
        PATINDEX('%associatedObjectId%', resource_description) + 19, 
        LEN(resource_description)) = p.partition_id
```

Answer (score 4):

You can try it :

```
SELECT 
db_name(rsc_dbid) AS 'DATABASE_NAME',
case rsc_type when 1 then 'null'
              when 2 then 'DATABASE' 
              WHEN 3 THEN 'FILE'
              WHEN 4 THEN 'INDEX'
              WHEN 5 THEN 'TABLE'
              WHEN 6 THEN 'PAGE'
              WHEN 7 THEN 'KEY'
              WHEN 8 THEN 'EXTEND'
              WHEN 9 THEN 'RID ( ROW ID)'
              WHEN 10 THEN 'APPLICATION' end  AS 'REQUEST_TYPE',

CASE req_ownertype WHEN 1 THEN 'TRANSACTION'
                   WHEN 2 THEN 'CURSOR'
                   WHEN 3 THEN 'SESSION'
                   WHEN 4 THEN 'ExSESSION' END AS 'REQUEST_OWNERTYPE',

OBJECT_NAME(rsc_objid ,rsc_dbid) AS 'OBJECT_NAME', 
PROCESS.HOSTNAME , 
PROCESS.program_name , 
PROCESS.nt_domain , 
PROCESS.nt_username , 
PROCESS.program_name ,
SQLTEXT.text 
FROM sys.syslockinfo LOCK JOIN 
     sys.sysprocesses PROCESS
  ON LOCK.req_spid = PROCESS.spid
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(PROCESS.SQL_HANDLE) SQLTEXT
```